# Episode: Batman trapped and escaping a Riddler like maze that is morphing

Tags: dc, episode-identification, dc-animated-universe, batman-the-animated-series

I am searching an episode of *Batman: The Animated Series* or related: I remember watching an animated Batman episode, where one villain, not sure if it was the Riddle, the Joke or else, setup an morphing maze, which usually can only be escaped by a specific key. I remember Batman breaking a "one sided" mirror or invisible glass to a control room, accessible from an elevator shaft, he had to climb up.

Al tough I would not rule out the possibility of misleading childhood memories, I am very certain I did not made that up. However I was not able to find it via episode lists or skipping over the episodes. Possibly it was in a spin off or something broadcast ed in the german television in the 90s. But it was definitely in the style of the animated series.

Comment: First "Batman in a maze" animated scene I think of is from _Justice League_, see [this clip](https://youtu.be/yJYRzNSLtHA?t=151). However what I remember from the plot of this episode doesn't match. I'll go check, but can you please take a look and confirm/deny?

Comment: @Jenayah No its not the clip you mentioned and definitely not in the justice league universe. But thank you very much for the try!

Comment: Potentially this episode with the Mad Hatter? https://batman.fandom.com/wiki/Perchance_to_Dream

Comment: @just_happen_to_know I have seen that episode recently, but its not the one.

Answer (score 4):

Batman: The Animated Series Season 2 Episode 12 - If You're So Smart, Why Aren't You Rich?

> Edward Nygma creates the video game The Riddle of the Minotaur for the company Competitron, but is fired by his superior Daniel Mockridge, who wants the profits for himself. Nygma vows revenge, and takes up the mantle of the Riddler two years later. While Batman sympathizes with Nygma, he and Robin find themselves forced to stop him before he kills Mockridge in a life-sized version of the Minotaur maze.

There is a clip of the maze [here](https://youtu.be/-i4lu_EvhlY).

Comment: That's the episode I know almost matches the plot I remembered perfectly, and which is the reason why I would not rule out the possibility of a misleading childhood recall, but it is not this one. There was only one key and the villain lost himself in that later. IIRC is was in a hotel based theme.